# Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'marca_filter.value' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I'm having a problem when using the attributes as filter the a catalog category view, the error is:

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'marca_filter.value' in 'where clause', query was: INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5a46446e7dce40_69908069` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2` AS `search_index`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '2' WHERE (category_ids_index.category_id = 4) AND (marca_filter.value  IN ('169'))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
```

Marca is a custom attribute of type text/varchar and Magento has multiple stores.

The thing that i'm guessing that marca_filter is a alias for a table but i cannot figure it out what table is.

How can i know what table marca_filter is? To see if the column is there
What could be the problem? How can i debug it more?

Comment: give us your collection code

Comment: Are you using any extension for the layered navigation?

Comment: I just "resolved". It was an extension which was doing a around plugin for Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder in which i think that it was missing the attritubte filter per store functionality. I just comented the pluging and now i can use the search

Comment: @Gianni Di Falco I have the same problem on magento 2.1.15, could you tell witch witch extension was a around plugin for Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder ?

Comment: @khadijaaitchrif Sorry i really do not remember

Answer (score 1):

I just **resolved**. It was an extension which was doing a around plugin for

> Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder

In which i think that it was missing the attribute filter per store functionality. I just commented the plugging and now i can use the search